# BIOS password remove as USB drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My laptop is broken. But I need to get the data persisted in the hard drive of the laptop. So I bought a hard drive enclosure and connect as usb drive to the my new laptop. But the drive is not showing. I think that is because of hard drive password. In the my old laptop I have set a hard drive password. How can resolve this ?

Comment: What broke on the old laptop?

Comment: Did you look in disk management?

Comment: @AndrewMorton mother board

Comment: @Moab yes. hard disk not showing

Answer (score 0):

What do you set hard drive password, if it is BIOS password pop up when your laptop starts, isn't Hard drive password, and if that password are encrypting your data (ex. bitlocker), you can't recover without that password it's impossible, what's your new laptop response to your old hard drive ?